# How do I update the widget content when activating buttons in pyqt6?

Tags: pyqt

How to make the content of qwidjet change when you click on the buttons. The first time you press the button, it is displayed, but the next press does not change anything.

Maybe you need to choose another widget for matplotlib diagram?

Tried the update(), repaint() methods nothing helped.

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MyCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MyCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.new_window = QWidget()
        self.new_window.setFixedSize(400, 600)

        self.button1 = QPushButton('1')
        self.button2 = QPushButton('2')

        self.box_button = QHBoxLayout()
        self.box_button.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.box_button.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.box_new = QVBoxLayout()
        self.box_new.addWidget(self.new_window)
        self.box_new.addLayout(self.box_button)

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.click1)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.click2)

        self.setLayout(self.box_new)

    def click1(self):
        sc = MyCanvas(self, width=5, height=5, dpi=100)
        cars = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
        data = [11, 22, 33, 44]

        sc.axes.pie(data, labels=cars)
        sc.axes.set_title('title_1')

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(sc)
        self.new_window.setLayout(layout)

    def click2(self):
        sc = MyCanvas(self, width=5, height=5, dpi=100)
        cars = ['11', '22', '33']
        data = [111, 222, 333]

        sc.axes.pie(data, labels=cars)
        sc.axes.set_title('title_2')

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(sc)
        self.new_window.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MyWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: If you only have one canvas at a time, your approach is wrong (including the attempt for your answer, which won't consider layout management of the parent). If you have multiple "pages", consider QStackedWidget; otherwise, update the properties of the canvas or, at least, delete the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

forgot to change the object to a new link
window = QWidget(self)

```
def click1(self):
    window = QWidget(self)
    window.setFixedSize(400, 600)
    sc = MyCanvas(self, width=5, height=5, dpi=100)
    cars = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    data = [11, 22, 33, 44]

    sc.axes.pie(data, labels=cars)
    sc.axes.set_title('title_1')

    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(sc)
    window.setLayout(layout)
    self.new_window = window
    self.new_window.show()
```